# TSV as input to sagemaker

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

Is there any way to use a tsv instead of a csv as the input into sagemaker's autopilot ?

Currently I'm inputting the data as such:

```
input_data_config = [{
      'DataSource': {
        'S3DataSource': {
          'S3DataType': 'S3Prefix',
          'S3Uri': 's3://{}/{}/train'.format(bucket,prefix)
        }
      },
      'TargetAttributeName': 'sentiment'
    }
  ]
```

this seems to work file for .csv files but fails for my .tsv files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a developer at AWS SageMaker. Autopilot currently only supports CSV data. While we are working on extending the support to more file formats: JSON, TSV, etc, this might be something that you can try to convert your .tsv file to .csv:

```
import csv

# read tab-delimited file
with open('yourfile.tsv','rb') as fin:
    cr = csv.reader(fin, delimiter='\t')
    filecontents = [line for line in cr]

# write comma-delimited file (comma is the default delimiter)
with open('yourfile.csv','wb') as fou:
    cw = csv.writer(fou, quotechar='', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
    cw.writerows(filecontents)
```

Hope this helps.

Ref: [How to convert a tab separated file to CSV format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5590631/how-to-convert-a-tab-separated-file-to-csv-format)

Comment: Is it possible to use quoted CSVs ? The probleme here is that my input data (text) contains a bunch of `,`'s